# How do I know which JDK package to install?

Tags: software-installation, downloads, jdk

I'm trying to download & install a JDK (Java Development Kit) from Oracle's website: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html

But I'm just not sure which package to select?
[image]

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64

CPU: Intel i7-10610U (8) @ 4.900GHz

Comment: Debian Package for Ubuntu.

Comment: Alternative: Open JDK is in the Ubuntu repositories, and tested to be fully compatible with your release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Using the Ubuntu Software application (or apt), of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu uses `.deb` file format like windows uses `.exe` and `.msi`
So download the `Linux x64 Debian Package`